# Hint for Putnam question, $x_n^2 - x_{n-1}x_{n+1} = 1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, contest-math

> Let $\{x_n\}$, $n \ge 0$ be a sequence of nonzero real numbers such that $x_n^2-x_{n-1} x_{n+1} = 1$ for $n \ge 1$. Prove that there exists a real number $a$ such that $x_{n+1} = a x_n - x_{n-1}$

For the context, this problem is a challenge question from the sequences section from my Calculus book. I would please like a hint, but if someone knows from which year exam this question is please do let me know, so I can look up the solution in case I can't solve it.

Among some of the things I tried is this:

Rearranging the equation we want to prove yields

$$x_{n+1} + x_{n-1} = a x_n$$

Rearranging $x_n^2-x_{n-1} x_{n+1} = 1$ yields $x_{n+1} = \dfrac {x_n^2 - 1}{x_{n-1}}$ and $x_{n-1} = \dfrac {x_n^2 - 1}{x_{n+1}}$. Thus we want to show that

$$x_{n+1} + x_{n-1} = \dfrac {x_n^2 - 1}{x_{n+1}} + \dfrac {x_n^2 - 1}{x_{n-1}}  = a x_n$$

However, my algebraic efforts did not yield any results.

Another method I tried is assuming the conclusion ($x_{n+1} = a x_n - x_{n-1}$), plugging it into $x_{n+1} = \dfrac {x_n^2 - 1}{x_{n-1}}$ and maybe working backwards, but this didn't work either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely for any given $n$ you can easily find an $a_n$ such that $x_{n+1} = a_n x_n-x_{n-1}$.

This $a_n$ is a fairly simple rational fraction involving only $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$.  The specific value of $a_1$ is determined from $x_1$ and $x_0$.

Now use that same form of $a_n$, replacing $n$ by $n+1$ to get $a_{n+1}$ as a similar rational fraction involving $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$.  In  that rational fraction, replace $x_{n+1}$ by your $\frac{x_n^2-1}{x_{n-1}}$ and now you have a rational fraction involving only $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$.  Simplify this fraction.  If it is the same as the original fraction for $a_n$ you have proven that $a_{n+1} = a_n$ and thus induction is established.

You would lose points on the Putnam if you are sloppy about how you state the induction, but this is the general idea of the proof.

BTW, I think this is from the early 70's.

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally managed to solve it! If you wouldn't mind, could you offer more insight on the problem? What motivation did you have for solving it this way, as opposed to the endless possibilities (such as some of the ones I tried)?

Comment: The insight was from the point of the problem: If they ask you to prove that this $a$ exists, then surely it does exist.  (BTW, in real research, you don't have this "it's a posed problem" advantage.  So maybe you would speculate that such an $a$ exists, but it might be a dead end.) And since $a$ does not depend on $n$, it should be possible to find its value from early values in the $x_n$ sequence.  Now that you have the value, the first technique that comes to mind to show that the same value works for all $n$ is induction.